# Short SQL command to return true if no field contains a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I would like to have a short form of the SQL-command (I am using Oracle SQL)

```
SELECT * from table1 
WHERE field1 not like '%test%' 
AND field2 not like '%test%' 
AND field3 not like '%test%'
```

Is there a syntax which is equivalent to that command? I was thinking about something like

```
SELECT * from table1 
WHERE '%test%' not in (field1, field2, field3)
```

but this syntax unfortunately doesn't work?! Many thanks for all tips and suggestions.

Comment: Can't use wildcards in an `IN` clause -- the first query is supported on every database I'm aware of.

Comment: I don't think such syntax exists, if anyone knows I'd be more than pleased to learn..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not really possible.

This transformation using one of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is very slightly shorter but there's only a few characters difference:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE NOT (field1 LIKE '%test%' OR
           field2 LIKE '%test%' OR 
           field3 LIKE '%test%')
```

There is also this hack that is shorter still, but I would advise against it because it will give you a reduction in performance of your query as well as introducing the possiblity of a bug if you change the string literal `'%test%'` to something that could contain an underscore, for example `'%te_st%'`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE (field1 + '_' + field2 + '_' + field3) NOT LIKE '%test%'
```

I think what you are already doing is the best solution.

Comment: I usually find that charindex() or instr() work faster than "like". If performance is an issue, you might try "charindex('test', Field1) > 0" instead of Field1 like '%test%'.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry mate, I don't think you'll find any statement shorter or more simple than the first statement in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (
    (field1 NOT LIKE '%test%') AND
    (field2 NOT LIKE '%test%') AND
    (field3 NOT LIKE '%test%')
THEN true
ELSE false AS truthiness
```